# How to move store swicther under the header text of a magento custom module page?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have created a custom module for Magento to change some custom attributes for products.

I have added a store switcher in the page.

[image: my custom module page]

My problem is its coming above the header text 'custom module', i want it to be shown below that.

in my layout file, i have written this to add store switcher.

`<layout>
    <adminhtml_custommodule_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher"></block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_custommodule_index>
</layout>`

I have not used any .phtml files.

Please help.

Comment: provide your full layout file.

Comment: I have this much only in my layout file.